# need help on awk command unmatched '

Tags: awk, csh

here is the awk command

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  row=1
  while ( getline < "routingTB.txt" > 0 )
  {
     if( row==1 )      { col_id=$1; for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) q_id[i]=$i }
     else if( row==2 )
     for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) { s[q_id[i]]=$i; s_id[q_id[i]]=$1 }
     else
     for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ )
     if( $i<s[q_id[i]] ) { s_id[q_id[i]]=$1; s[q_id[i]]=$i }
   row++
 }
 }
 {  print $1, (NR>1 ? s_id[$1] : col_id) , $3 } ' query.txt
```

this command is used to do the following things

I have two files
file1:

```
query times attributes
q1 345 a1,a2
q2 547 a1,a4,a5
q5 967 a1
```

file2:

```
solution q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
s1 3425 1346 758 2245 928
s2 145 243 2983 1890 899
s3 333 209 1779 230 902
```

desire output:

```
query solution attributes
q1 s2 a1,a2
q2 s3 a1,a4,a5
q5 s2 a1
```

the error log is saying "unmatched '."

I have no idea what's happening. I only have two single quotes. need help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need a shebang line at the top of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

The error is a result of csh not knowing how to parse the input.  Stop using csh.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to put scripts in a file so that it will be easier to understand.

**nothing changed, I just put your script in a file and indented it**

```
bash-3.2$ cat sample.awk
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        row=1
        while ( getline < "routingTB.txt" > 0 )   {
                if( row==1 )      {
                        col_id=$1;
                        for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) q_id[i]=$i
                }
                else if( row==2 )
                        for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ )
                        {
                                s[q_id[i]]=$i; s_id[q_id[i]]=$1
                        }
                else  for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ )
                        if( $i<s[q_id[i]] ) { s_id[q_id[i]]=$1; s[q_id[i]]=$i }
                row++
        }
}
{
        print $1, (NR>1 ? s_id[$1] : col_id) , $3
}
bash-3.2$
```

**Executing your script**

```
bash-3.2$ awk -f sample.awk query.txt
query solution attributes
q1 s2 a1,a2
q2 s3 a1,a4,a5
q5 s2 a1
```